# React-Router - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browserify

I'm using the latest version of `react-router` (version ^3.0.0).

I wrote the following routing using ES5:

`routes.js`:

```
var React = require("react");
var Router = require("react-router");
var AuthorPage = require('./components/authors/authorPage')
var App = require('./components/app')
var Route = Router.Route;

var routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="authors" component={AuthorPage}/>
     </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

In another JS file called `main.js` I perform the following call:

`main.js`:

```
var React= require("react");
var ReactDom = require("react-dom");
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var routes = require('./routes');
ReactDom.render(<Router routes={routes}></Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

When I run the code I get the following exception in Google Chrome developer tools:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of
>   undefined

Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are not passing a history to your `<Router>`.

Check out the [histories documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/guides/Histories.md) for more information.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same error, solved it this way:

Add

```
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;
```

And in the Router set the history equals to hashHistory

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
```

So in your case:

```
var routes = (
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="authors" component={AuthorPage}/>
     </Route>
</Router>
);
```